# How do I make query use exact post title

Tags: query-posts

I am creating a custom search query in wordpress and the post title isn't matching. I want it to say the posttitle and the firstname have to be exact matches, or nothing should come up under the results. My Post_titles are all 5 digits numbers. But as of right now, I can type in the correct firstname but use any numbers that don't match the post title and it still shows up. Both need to be exact matches. Any suggestions on what to do here?

```
<?php 
               /* Search Results */ 



 $args = array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_type' => 'patients', 'post_title' => $patientid,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'firstname',
        'value'   => $firstname,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
),);

            query_posts($args);
  ?>
```